# What are the advantages/differences of creating/using a plugin in play framework 2 over modules?

Tags: java, plugins, module, playframework-2.0

I am relatively new to Play Framework 2 and I was wondering What are the advantages/differences of creating/using a plugin in play framework 2 over modules?
I mean why would you add something to your project through developing a plugin and why through creating a module? am I mixing things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module is just a play app that is meant to be used in another app rather than stand alone, so basically a play project which results in a jar that you can depend on/include in a play app. It could contain utility classes, prewritten controllers, templates etc. that you would explicitly include or use in your app. Here is a good tutorial about writing modules: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363

A plugin will be bound to the play app lifecycle, so that you can setup and initialize resources on app startup and clean them out on stop. Examples are database connection pools, stuff that gets cached because initialization is expensive, could also be stuff that should not live across application restarts that you would normally put in a singleton, which will break the tests since the same singleton will be reused across multiple App instances when running the tests.

A lot of the play parts are actually implemented as plugins if take a look under the hood.

Plugins are often distributed as modules but they can also be a part of the application code base.